# RxJs Observables subscribe multiple values and retrieve particular value

Tags: rxjs

```js
const observable = Rx.Observable.create( observer => {
    observer.next( 'hello' )
    observer.next( 'world' )
})

observable.subscribe(val => console.log(val))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/rxjs/4.1.0/rx.min.js"></script>
```

In this above script, when we subscribe, we get both values (hello and world). How do we get individual values separately. Example: We want to get only the 2nd value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `skip()`-operator.

```
import { skip } from 'rxjs/operators';

observable.pipe(skip(1)).subscribe(val => console.log(val))
```

If you don't just want to skip values but filter them, `filter()` is your rxjs-function of choice. Because here, equal to the filter-method of an array, you can define a so called `predicate` which is the condition by which an object passes or gets dropped.

Here is a small example. It only lets strings pass that contain an uppercase `A`.

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';
import {filter} from 'rxjs/operators';

private observable: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.observable.pipe(filter(value => value.includes('A'))).subscribe(val => console.log(val));

    this.observable.next('AA');
    this.observable.next('BA');
    this.observable.next('BB');
    this.observable.next('CC');
    this.observable.next('DD');
    this.observable.next('DA');
    this.observable.next('AD');
}
```

Comment: PS: If this solved your question, please, be so kind and mark this answer as solution.

Comment: Thanks for your option @lynx 242. Sure I will do. Is there any other option available kind of key value? instead of skipping with number.

Comment: So, I extended my solution. Hope this helps. Once again, please, don't forget to mark the solution as solution. Thanks in advance.